# Heroku config variables appear in console but are set to None when accessing with os.environ.get

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

I'm trying to upload files to an S3 bucket and I'm using [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) tutorial. I'm setting config variables in the terminal using `heroku config:set` and when I enter `heroku config` in the terminal, my variables appear.

[image]

However, if I access `S3_BUCKET` in code when running locally, the value returned is None:

```
S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')
print("value of S3_BUCKET: " + S3_BUCKET)
```

This prints `None`.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? The frontend of my application is in React, if that matters, but all of the bucket upload code is done in python.

Comment: I would pass the app name too: `heroku config:set VAR=value -a appname`

Comment: "if I access `S3_BUCKET` in code"—do you mean when the code is running on Heroku, or during local development?

Comment: @Chris During local development

Comment: @BeppeC Yup, did that when I ran the command, I just didn't show it in the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku config:set` sets variables *on Heroku*. Like their name suggests, environment variables are specific to a particular environment. Settings set this way have no impact on your local machine.

There are several ways to set environment variables locally. One common method involves putting them into an untracked `.env` file. Many tools, including `heroku local`, read that file and add variables found there to the environment when running locally.

Heroku [recommends this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file), though you will have to make sure whatever tooling you use picks up those variables. Aside from `heroku local`, [Visual Studio Code understands `.env` files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) for Python projects. [So does Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env). There are also standalone tools for this like [direnv](https://direnv.net/).